# resources to create data collection map in R or Python?

Tags: python, r, maps, interactive

I am trying to create an interactive map in R or Python that could be hosted on a website and shared via a link. Creating interactive map is no problem, however I want users with the link to be able to edit the map.

i.e zoom into an area and click on a point and add data to the map.

I would be happy to use R or Python to do this but cannot find any resources to put me in the correct direction. All the resources I am seeing are using pre-existing data whereas I want to create new data on the map and allow others with access to be able to edit to.

Does anyone know some good resources for this type of application?

Thank you.

Comment: Do the other contributors have a working knowledge of R or Python? If so, `leaflet` is the way to go. Dataset and code on github of course.

Comment: No thats the problem! I would want it to be as simple as click on an area and have a GUI data input box open up. Similiar to ARCGIS or QGIS but hosted on R or Python.....

Comment: I've created interactive maps with leaflet, with markers etc but only with hard coded markers. Is there a way to make it simpler for someone who doesnt code.

Comment: If the idea is simply adding labels and other text, I don't see why you couldn't maybe hold a 30-minute training session to show others where they should input data and run the code. But I concede even that would be a challenge to R/Python novices.

Comment: Its being sent to farmers, foresters and ecologists who have very limited IT skills. Simplicity is the aim to get widespread participation

Comment: I'm not aware of a platform with that functionality but it doesn't mean there isn't one out there. Sorry I can't help.